# HTML5 data-attributes : How to modify array of data attached to DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I try to modify some HTML5 data-attribute with jquery.

I know how to do when it is simple like this :

```
<div id="element" data-options="HelloWorld"></div>

//Modify with jQuery :
$("#element").data("options","Bye Bye");
```

But in my case, i would like to modify a more complexe data-options (it's a joomla module).

data-options is organized like this with an array of datas :

```
data-options="{"title":"Test","lat":"48.6069129","lng":"7.7612831","icon":"red","popup":1},{"title":"Test","lat":"48.6069129","lng":"7.7612831","icon":"blue","popup":2}"
```

How can i select and modify only icon for example ?

Comment: You will simply need to convert it from a string to an object using JSON parsing. The double-quotes are going to cause you grief though.

Comment: Ensure that you use the correct quotes, as it stands the value is invalid.

Comment: How will the JSON literal be injected into the elements? Is that server-side (if so what technology are you using server-side)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function overload of `jQuery.fn.data`

```
$('#element').data('options', function(data){
   var obj = JSON.parse(data);
   obj.forEach(function(o){
       o.icon = "some other color";
   });
   return JSON.stringify(obj);
});
```

The above works assuming you have the following as your data.

```
'[{"title":"Test","lat":"48.6069129","lng":"7.7612831","icon":"red","popup":1},{"title":"Test","lat":"48.6069129","lng":"7.7612831","icon":"blue","popup":2}]'
```

To properly declare the json, you can put 'em in `''` instead of `""` which will save you from the headache of escaping double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

From comment: You will simply need to convert it from a string to an object using JSON parsing. The double-quotes are going to cause you grief though.

```
 var values = $.parseJSON($('#element').data('options'));
```

One only way to include a JSON literal in a standard HTML attribute is by encoding the `"`'s to `&quot;`s which is pretty horrible:

e.g.

```
data-options=";{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Test&quot;,&quot;lat&quot;:&quot;48.6069129&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;7.7612831&quot;,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;red&quot;,&quot;popup&quot;:1},{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Test&quot;,&quot;lat&quot;:&quot;48.6069129&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;7.7612831&quot;,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;blue&quot;,&quot;popup&quot;:2}";
```

or you can use single quotes for the delimiting (while not standard this will work on most browsers):

```
data-options='{"title":"Test","lat":"48.6069129","lng":"7.7612831","icon":"red","popup":1},{"title":"Test","lat":"48.6069129","lng":"7.7612831","icon":"blue","popup":2}'
```

Comment: Close enough but `<a data-options='json string can go here'></a>`. Note that I've used a `'` instead of `"`

Comment: @Amit Joki: Noted with disclaimer (as that is non-standard and sometimes not possible depending on the tech used).

Comment: I wanted to ask you to clarify your comment about the quote. Thank you for your answer, now, i understand. I didn’t code this Joomla module (widgetkit map). But I can easily replace double quote by single quote.

Comment: @Sébastien Gicquel: In that case single quotes will do: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: I'm ok with the &quote format it works http://jsfiddle.net/estuqq26/1/  and if used in Rails application ERB is rendering it like that  (http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/12-json-array-in-html-element-data-attribute)